# Single Statement Fibonacci

Tags: python, list-comprehension, fibonacci

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fibonacci numbers, with an one-liner in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935957/fibonacci-numbers-with-an-one-liner-in-python-3)

It may be very easy thing, but I am very new to Python. I came up with this single statement Fibonacci.

```
[fibs.append(fibs[-2]+fibs[-1]) for i in xrange(1000)]
```

Not really single statement, though. I need to initialise the list, `fibs`, before firing this statement i.e. `fibs = [0, 1]`.

Now, I have 2 questions,

1. How can we get rid of this list initialisation statement, `fibs = [0, 1]`, in order to make it really single statement?
2. Original statement prints `None` *n* times; where *n* is the number passed in `xrange()`. Is there any way to avoid that altogether? Or better if the statement can print the series, instead. Then we don't need to print `fibs` explicitly.

**[Edited]**

Or do we have any alternative to `list.append()` which returns the `list` it appends to?

Comment: Why does it have to be a single statement? A generator would be much more suitable in this situation.

Comment: @Felix: Just playing, it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
for n in range(1000):
    print(0.4472135954999579392818347337462552470881236719223051448541*(pow(1.6180339887498948482045868343656381177203091798057628621354,n) - pow(-0.618033988749894848204586834365638117720309179805762862135,n)))
```

This is an implementation of Binet's Formula.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio

Comment: It should work for Python's `int` numbers, but it is still precision-dependant and I wouldn't rely on it. Nice thought, though :)

Comment: If Python supported(supports?) symbolic Mathematics, this would be solvable exactly for all n >=1 within limitations of the largest available variable size.
(I'm not a Python developer, here. :P.)

Comment: I am no pro of floating point, so I'll keep reserve, but I still think that introducing floats in pure integer context is wicked. Didn't deserve the downvote, though.

Comment: Although +1 for the implimentation

Comment: I could have sworn that I wrote O(log(n)) time, but apparently when it's 6:00 A.M. and you haven't slept, you start replacing log(n) with 1. X_X. It's been a long night in the house. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is not idiomatic at all. What you are doing here is using a list comprehension as a shortcut for a `for` loop. Though Python's  comprehensions can have side effects, Python is not designed for this. I can't think of no way to get this to work and it is probably a good thing.

For your 2), consider that you are actually creating a list which items are return values of the call `fibs.append(fibs[-2]+fibs[-1])` which is a side effect method and thus return `None`. See [the doc](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) for details.

Nice try but this is not what Python is for :)

Comment: Suppose if it were implemented as, where `append()` returns the `list`. Then it would have been possible to do something like this, `list.append().append().append()`. I don't see any problem with this.

Comment: @Adeel Ansari It's just that it is not idiomatic, that's all. Python is as much a coding style as a language. As for why side effects return `None`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567409/python-image-library-how-to-combine-4-images-into-a-2-x-2-grid/4568169#4568169. To do chained append, consider http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-bytes-bytearray-list-tuple-range sequence `+` operator.

Comment: Evpok: Thanks, I do agree with the first. For 2nd I came up with a dirty work-around, as dirty as I got 2 negative votes :). Folks doesn't understand that it was just for fun. Anyways, +1 for your inputs.

Comment: Dirty Python code is evil, but fun is excuse enough. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def fib(n):
    return (n in (0,1) and [n] or [fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)])[0]
```

try this out

Comment: if you want you can also use a lambda expression like this one: lambda n: (n in (0,1) and [n] or [fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)])[0] but you better understand how it works :)

Comment: Firstly, its very slow, as you can see. Secondly, I know we can come up with a function/method and then keep calling that as a single statement. That is not what I want. Thirdly, your solution is just giving me the last value, not the complete series.

Comment: @Adeel: I know its not what you are looking for but speaking performance...you should try this: **return ((1+math.sqrt(5))**n-(1-math.sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*math.sqrt(5))**

Comment: @Adeel, maozet This is known as Binet's Formula and it is what I implemented in another answer.