# Print Fibonacci Series using lambda and map or reduce in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, lambda

- I want to **print Fibonacci Series using lambda()** function with **map() or reduce()** function in Python.

**Note:** I did search on SO, but could only find questions related to Printing nth Fibonacci number. e.g [Fibonacci numbers, with an one-liner in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935957/fibonacci-numbers-with-an-one-liner-in-python-3)

Comment: This is stackoverflow, not code golf.

Comment: What is the problem in sharing a tricky situation, I faced with all. ? ...  even SO recommends it read: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: It's okay (and encouraged) to ask and answer your own *on-topic* questions.  This is a **bad** question, any way you slice it.  This site is about solving programming problems, not a competition to see who can produce a "one liner".

Comment: @roppi ..See the link of the question I provided in the text.. it was also similar but it did help other people..

Answer (score 8):

**I have the following working solutions:**

A. Using **lambda() + reduce()**:

> ```
>  >>> fib = lambda n: reduce(lambda x, _: x+[x[-1]+x[-2]], range(n-2), [0, 1])
>  >>> fib(10)
>  >>> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
> ```

Note: **Not able to use x.append(x[-1]+x[-2])**. Gives AttributeError (Don't know why)

B. Using **lambda() + map()**: (Have to use a variable for result)

> ```
>  >>> result = [0,1]
>  >>> fib = lambda n: map(lambda _: result.append(result[-1] + result[-2]), xrange(n-2))
>  >>> fib(10)                          ## Ignore its output ##
>  >>> result                           ## Stores the result ##
>  >> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
> ```

Comment: I see two problems with your lambda() + reduce() solution.  The first is you avoid doing a *reduction* by ignoring the second `lambda()` argument and treat `reduce()` as a simple iterator .  The second problem is that `fib(1)` and `fib(2)` produce the same result but they shouldn't.

Comment: about your note, that is because `x.append(...)` return `None` because is a operation in place of list, while reduce expect your the function to return a value that is going to be used in the next iteration, for that you can do this `(x.append(...),x)[1]`

Comment: I see two problems with your lambda() + map() solution.  The first is that it doesn't work in Python 3 as its extreme lazy evaluation doesn't fill out `result` until something consumes the result of  `map()`.  (E.g. try wrapping your `map()` in an `any()`)  The second problem is that `fib(1)` and `fib(2)` produce the same result but they shouldn't.

Comment: the solution to problem that _cdlane_ mention, is to add `[:n]` to the list `[0,1]` -> `[0,1][:n]`

Comment: @Copperfield `fib = lambda n: reduce(lambda x, _: x+[x[-1]+x[-2]], range(n-1), [0, 1])[:-1]` also works.

Answer (score 2):

Fibonacci using reduce() and lambda()

```
from functools import reduce

def fibonacci(count):
    sequence = (0, 1)

    for _ in range(2, count):
        sequence += (reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, sequence[-2:]), )

    return sequence[:count]

print(fibonacci(10))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34)
```

Fibonacci using map() and lambda()

```
def fibonacci(count):
    sequence = [0, 1]

    any(map(lambda _: sequence.append(sum(sequence[-2:])), range(2, count)))

    return sequence[:count]

print(fibonacci(10))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Comment: in the first version I rather use a list and append

Answer (score 1):

---

### Code Snippet:

```
fibonacci = lambda number: number if number <= 1 else fibonacci(number - 1) + fibonacci(number - 2);
listOfFibonacciNumbers = list(map(fibonacci, range(0, 20, 1)));
print(listOfFibonacciNumbers);
```

---

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181]
```

In place of 20, you can give your number.
I hope this helps:)

Answer (score 0):

yo can try this for Fibonacci using reduce() and lambda()

```
def Fib(count):
    first =[0,1]
    for i in range(0,count-2):
        first.append(reduce(lambda x,y : x+y,first[-2:]))

    print(first) 
Fib(10)
```

### output

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what might help you!
**Implemented using `reduce()` and `lambda`**

```
from functools import reduce

fibonacci_seq = [0, 1]
n = 10

reduce(lambda a, b: len(fibonacci_seq) < n and (fibonacci_seq.append(a+b) or a+b), fibonacci_seq)
```

`(fibonacci_seq.append(a+b) or a+b)` : as the `<any_list>.append(ele)` returns `None`, I'm using it to append the next element in the series to the `fibonacci_seq`. `or`ing it with `a+b` allows to return `a+b` as the result to the `reduce()` function to operate on it with the next element in the sequence.

`len(fibonacci_seq) < n` : The list stops growing once the len(list) reaches n.

**OUTPUT**

```
print(fibonacci_seq)

>>> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

The above method returns the right sequence for n = 2 onwards.

Answer (score -2):

try this code which prints the first 10 Fibonacci numbers using LAMBDA

fib = lambda n: n if n<=1 else fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)

for i in range(10):print(fib(i))

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit your answer and format your code as code. Also some description would be nice, it's not "look how clever one liner I wrote" site.