# I was try to solve Python program to create Fibonacci series using Lambda, but I unable to solve it

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, underscore.js, fibonacci

So on internet they solve using:

```
from functools import reduce

fib = lambda n: reduce(lambda x, _: x+[x[-1]+x[-2]],range(n-2), [0, 1])

print(fib(5))
```

[Fibonacci program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5e4j.png)

I don't understand what's the use of underscore _ and actually how this range(n-2) is working inside program

Comment: Refer to this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453007/print-fibonacci-series-using-lambda-and-map-or-reduce-in-python

Comment: `_` is just a variable name. It is commonly used to indicate that you are ignoring a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fib = lambda n: ...` creates a one liner lambda function and assigns it to `fib`. Now, `fib` is a callable like a function e.g. `fib(5)`.

`reduce` accepts 3 params: `reduce(function, iterable, [, initializer])`.

`lambda x, _: x+[x[-1]+x[-2]]` is your `function`. It concats current `x` sequence to a single-element sequence of sum of last and second last elements in the sequence `x` (see table below).

`range(n-2)` is `iterable` which generates a sequence of numbers `[0,1,2]` for `n=5`.

`[0, 1]` is the initial sequence to start with i.e. first 2 fixed numbers in fib sequence.

`_` is used as second argument of `function` which is ignored. It is a convention to use `_` for ignored argument in a functional program. The second argument receives one value from `iterable` for each run i.e. `0`, `1`, & `2`.

**Dry run for n=5**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
range(n-2)            x    _    x+[x[-1]+x[-2]]         output
--------------------------------------------------------------
         0        [0,1]    0        [0,1]+[0+1]        [0,1,1]
         1      [0,1,1]    1      [0,1,1]+[1+1]      [0,1,1,2]
         2    [0,1,1,2]    2    [0,1,1,2]+[1+2]    [0,1,1,2,3]
```

**Note:** `[0,1] + [0+1]` is list concatenation of `[0,1]` and `[1]`