# Why is time complexity O(1) for pow(x,y) while it is O(n) for x**y?

Tags: python, asymptotic-complexity

Why is time complexity O(1) of `pow(x,y)` while it is O(n) for `x ** y`?

Check comment from [agf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500584/agf) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800193/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-finding-all-the-factors-of-a-number-in-python#6800214)

Comment: You’re right – that doesn’t sound accurate. (It originates from a comment by unseen_rider.)

Comment: Wish I could comment and ask both of them there :-)

Comment: That comment is nonsense. For an integer `n`, both `pow(n, 0.5)` and `n ** 0.5` will simply end up calling the underlying C library's `pow`. (Personally, I'd go with `sqrt` every time: it's much more likely to be correctly rounded and unlikely to be noticeably slower than `pow` or `**`)

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969773/exponentials-in-python-x-y-vs-math-powx-y), `**`is faster for `float` values, whereas `pow`is faster for `int` values due to the optional modulus argument to the builtin pow.

Comment: @RunOrVeith: `pow(x, y)` is faster for `int` values only when you want to do `float` exponentiation anyway, but they still have the same time complexity.

Comment: According to [Modular Exponentiation] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation), the memory efficient method is to calculate the modulus on the go instead of leaving it till the exponential is calculated. However, I couldn't understand how it is memory efficient when the modulus is 1?

Comment: @KumarTanmay When the modulus is 1, the result will always be 0. So first calculating a big number and then returning 0 at the end would mean you'd have to store that big number in memory until the end. If you mod with 0 along the way, you'll never get to that big number and you'll only store 0 in memory.

Answer (score 41):

The statement is wrong.

- `pow` is more or less identical to `**`.
- `pow` and `**` do integer exponentiation if their arguments are integers. (Python 3 has automatic bignum support, so, for example, `a ** b` always gives the exact integral result, even if a or b are very large.)  This takes O(log(b)) multiplications with exponentiation by squaring, but bignum multiplication isn't constant time, so the time complexity depends on details of the multiplication algorithm used. (Also, Python doesn't quite use exponentiation by squaring, but what Python does use still takes O(log(b)) multiplications.)
- `math.pow`, on the other hand, is different. It always does floating point exponentiation and is always O(1). That O(1) complexity isn't because it's any more efficient than `pow` or `**`; it's because floating point sacrifices accuracy and range. For cases where the non-constant complexity of integer exponentiation actually matters, `math.pow` will give much less precise results or throw an `OverflowError`.

Further details (from reviewing [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20969773/25507) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10282674/25507) on Stack Overflow, and from poking a bit at the Python source):

- `pow` (see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/01423cb53b5662b363d2f1a5963eadfe951ef3e8/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1827)) and `**` (see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/667b91a5e210e20946ad41f1796c544a1becf1b6/Python/ceval.c#L1184)) both call the same `PyNumber_Power` function. In practice, `**` can be faster, because it avoids the overhead of an extra symbol lookup and function call.
- The integer implementation of `pow` / `**` can be seen [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/667b91a5e210e20946ad41f1796c544a1becf1b6/Objects/longobject.c#L4020).
- `math.pow`, on the other hand, always calls the C library's `pow` function, which always does floating point math. (See [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/667b91a5e210e20946ad41f1796c544a1becf1b6/Modules/mathmodule.c#L2084) and [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/667b91a5e210e20946ad41f1796c544a1becf1b6/Modules/mathmodule.c#L2137).) This is often faster, but it's not precise. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40824889/25507) for one way that `pow` might be implemented.
- For floating point numbers, `pow` / `**` also call the C library's `pow` function, so there's no difference. See [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/667b91a5e210e20946ad41f1796c544a1becf1b6/Objects/floatobject.c#L685) and [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/667b91a5e210e20946ad41f1796c544a1becf1b6/Objects/floatobject.c#L789).

You can paste these commands into your IPython session if you want to play with this yourself:

```
import timeit

def show_timeit(command, setup):
    print(setup + '; ' + command + ':')
    print(timeit.timeit(command, setup))
    print()

# Comparing small integers
show_timeit('a ** b', 'a = 3; b = 4')
show_timeit('pow(a, b)', 'a = 3; b = 4')
show_timeit('math.pow(a, b)', 'import math; a = 3; b = 4')

# Compare large integers to demonstrate non-constant complexity
show_timeit('a ** b', 'a = 3; b = 400')
show_timeit('pow(a, b)', 'a = 3; b = 400')
show_timeit('math.pow(a, b)', 'import math; a = 3; b = 400')

# Compare floating point to demonstrate O(1) throughout
show_timeit('a ** b', 'a = 3.; b = 400.')
show_timeit('pow(a, b)', 'a = 3.; b = 400.')
show_timeit('math.pow(a, b)', 'import math; a = 3.; b = 400.')
```