# fibonacci specific number generator python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, fibonacci

Is there a way to show the N<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number? e.g. I want the 15<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci Number, but this only gives a list.

```
a = int(input('Enter N Number: '))

def fib(n):
    a = b = 1
    for i in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

print(fib(a))
```

Comment: print(list(fib(a)))***

Comment: list(fib(a))[-1] should do it

Comment: if you have the list l, you can access element nr 15 by l[14].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the result of `fib()` to a list and index it at `-1`:

```
print(list(fib(a))[-1])

>> Enter N Number: 15
>> [610]
```

Comment: but i only want the Nth number that I put in e.g. the 7th Fibonacci Number
and the list is giving out more than I want

Comment: Check the answer again

Answer (score 7):

A naive approach would be to generate all *n* Fibonacci numbers and return the last element which takes `O(n)` time. You can calculate *N<sup>th</sup>Fibonacci number* in `O(1)`(assuming `math.pow` takes `O(1)` time) using *[Binet's Formula.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Binet's_formula)*

Binet's Formula:

```
Fib(n) =(Phin − (−Phi)−n)/√5
```

Where

- `Phi=(1+√5)/2= and -Phi=(1-√5)/2`
- `(1+√5)/2` is also called *[Golden Ratio.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)*

```
import math
def fib(n):
    phi=1.61803398874989484820
    return round(((math.pow(phi,n))-(math.pow(-(1-phi),n)))/math.sqrt(5))

fib(15)
# 610
fib(10)
# 55
```

Mathematical proof and calculator *[here.](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html)*

Comment: There is an extra `return` there. Also, I computed 300 fibonacci number with a plain recursive function with memoization and got `222232244629420445529739893461909967206666939096499764990979600` in `0.23246139999999998` secs. With *Binet's Formula* I got `222232244629422676106398124069050176556246085874450435841982464` in `0.9962692000000001` secs. Notice it took longer and with a difference of `2230576658230607140209349579146777950670851002864`. What do you think about this?

Comment: @DarK_FirefoX How did you time your results? Using timeit? Can post a link using repl here.

Comment: I did use `timeit` here it [is](https://repl.it/@DarKFirefoX/fibonacci) Share your thoughts

Comment: @DarK_FirefoX Using *Binet's* formula for large values of *n* we get approx value(Mentioned in the link at the bottom of the answer). And for the reason why memoization is faster because of `n**300` takes lot of time though it's asymptotically `O(1)`. I guess using memoization is better. Post it as answer. I'll sure upvote. ;)

Comment: Thanks. Also I may have to dig deeper cause I am failing to see that *power* operations on python were O(1) unless there is a machine code instruction (which I don't really remember :P). I thought they were O(log n). Definitely will look into that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48839772/12416453 here's an answer about pow and its time complexity @DarK_FirefoX

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the Nth-Fibonacci Number using recursion with [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

**Why?**

For instance: imagine you are to compute `fibonacci(5)` so you need to compute `fibonacci(4)` and `fibonacci(3)`. But now, for `fibonacci(4)` you need to compute `fibonacci(3)` and `fibonacci(2)`, and so on. But wait, when you finish computing `fibonacci(4)` branch you already computed all fibonacci for 3 and 2, so when you go back to the other branch (`fibonacci(3)`) from the first recursive call, you already have computed it. So, What if there is a way I can store those calculations so I can access them faster? You can do it with [Decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) to create a [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) class (some sort of memory to avoid repeated calculations):

This way we are going to store each computation of `fibonacci(k)` on a `dict` and we would check each time before a call if it exists on the dictionary, return if `True` or else compute it. This way is faster and accurate.

```
class memoize:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.f = function
        self.memory = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if args in self.memory:
            return self.memory[args]
        else:
            value = self.f(*args)
            self.memory[args] = value
            return value

@memoize
def fib(n):
  if n <= 1:
    return n
  else:
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

r = fib(300)
print(r)
```

**Outputs:**

```
222232244629420445529739893461909967206666939096499764990979600
```

It only took `0.2716239` secs.

Comment: Nice answer. ;) +1 Note: This answer is accurate and faster than Binet's formula approach for large *n*.

Comment: Why not using [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) ?

Comment: @ChihebNexus, you are totally right, more than a valid approach. However wanted to go beyond simple pythonic way of doing things and lay out some programming concepts to the OP,  meaning: creating a wrapper class for a decorator, concept of memoization and of course how to notice duplicated calls on this specific use case. Although, it would be nice to explain how to use `lru_cache` for others. Feel free to do it in an answer, would be helpful. Greetings

Comment: @DarK_FirefoX Done. And you can compare the performance results.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach of the answer posted by @DarK_FirefoX using the concept of [`memoization`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) within the built-in function [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) which is a:

> Decorator to wrap a function with a memoizing callable that saves up
>   to the maxsize most recent calls. It can save time when an expensive
>   or I/O bound function is periodically called with the same arguments.

```
from functools import lru_cache 


@lru_cache() 
def fib(n): 
    if n <= 1: 
        return n 
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

print(fib(300))
# 222232244629420445529739893461909967206666939096499764990979600
```

**Bonus:**

```
$> %timeit fib(300)                                                        
78.2 ns ± 0.453 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments your program can be used to generate the Nth number by taking the last in the sequence, i.e.

```
list(fib(n))[-1]
```

However, there are more efficient programs for just generating the Nth fibonacci number as discussed [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/)

One such example is the 6th program from this source, i.e.:

```
# Python 3 Program to find n'th fibonacci Number in 
# with O(Log n) arithmatic operations 
MAX = 1000

# Create an array for memoization 
f = [0] * MAX

# Returns n'th fuibonacci number using table f[] 
def fib(n) : 
    # Base cases 
    if (n == 0) : 
        return 0
    if (n == 1 or n == 2) : 
        f[n] = 1
        return (f[n]) 

    # If fib(n) is already computed 
    if (f[n]) : 
        return f[n] 

    if( n & 1) : 
        k = (n + 1) // 2
    else :  
        k = n // 2

    # Applyting above formula [Note value n&1 is 1 
    # if n is odd, else 0. 
    if((n & 1) ) : 
        f[n] = (fib(k) * fib(k) + fib(k-1) * fib(k-1)) 
    else : 
        f[n] = (2*fib(k-1) + fib(k))*fib(k) 

    return f[n] 


# Driver code 
n = 9
print(fib(n)
```

**Output**

```
34
```

**Advantage over Posted Code**

The advantage of this approach is the complexity is *O(log(n))* for the nth fibonacci number, while the posted code from the question has complexity O(n).