# What is the time complexity of type casting function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

For example, 
 `int(x)`
 `float(x)`
 `str(x)`
What is time complexity of them?

Comment: It depends on the argument type. `int(x)` is O(1) if `x` is already an `int`, but it's O(n) for a `str` of length `n`.

Comment: btw, there is no casting in python. What you are using are conversion functions.

Comment: `str` can be arbitrarily complex because it calls the object's `__str__` method which is free to do whatever it likes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no definite answer to this because it depends not just what type you're converting to, but also what type you're converting from.

Let's consider just numbers and strings. To avoid writing "log" everywhere, we'll measure the size of an `int` by saying n is how many bits or digits it takes to represent it. (Asymptotically it doesn't matter if you count bits or digits.) For strings, obviously we should let n be the length of the string. There is no meaningful way to measure the "input size" of a `float` object, since floating-point numbers all take the same amount of space.

- Converting an `int`, `float` or `str` to its own type ought to take Θ(1) time because they are immutable objects, so it's not even necessary to make a copy.
- Converting an `int` to a `float` ought to take Θ(1) time because you only need to read at most a fixed constant number of bits from the `int` object to find the mantissa, and the bit length to find the exponent.
- Converting an `int` to a `str` ought to take Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) time, because you have to do Θ(n) division and remainder operations to find n digits, and each arithmetic operation takes Θ(n) time because of the size of the integers involved.
- Converting a `str` to an `int` ought to take Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) time because you need to do Θ(n) multiplications and additions on integers of size Θ(n).
- Converting a `str` to a `float` ought to take Θ(n) time. The algorithm only needs to read a fixed number of characters from the string to do the conversion, and floating-point arithmetic operations (or operations on bounded `int` values to avoid intermediate rounding errors) for each character take Θ(1) time; but the algorithm needs to look at the rest of the characters anyway in order to raise a `ValueError` if the format is wrong.
- Converting a `float` to any type takes Θ(1) time because there are only finitely many distinct `float` values.

I've said "ought to" because I haven't checked the actual source code; this is based on what the conversion algorithms need to do, and the assumption that the algorithms actually used aren't asymptotically worse than they need to be.

There could be special cases to optimise the `str`-to-`int` conversion when the base is a power of 2, like `int('11001010', 2)` or `int('AC5F', 16)`, since this can be done without arithmetic. If those cases are optimised then they should take Θ(n) time instead of Θ(n<sup>2</sup>). Likewise, converting an `int` to a `str` in a base which is a power of 2 (e.g. using the `bin` or `hex` functions) should take Θ(n) time.

Comment: why conversion of str->int and str->float are not the same?

Comment: I think str->int takes O(n), you can easily do it over looping the string, then sum `sum_ += i * 10**end_index` end_index is the last element's index in str

Comment: @Rustam-Z That would also be an O(n^2) algorithm. `10**end_index` takes O(n) time because it creates an `int` object with O(n) bits, and the additions would be O(n) each for the same reason.

Comment: the complexity of math.pow(x, y) is O(1) -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839772/why-is-time-complexity-o1-for-powx-y-while-it-is-on-for-xy

Comment: @Rustam-Z That's simply wrong. Read the answer on your link.

Answer (score -2):

Float(x) is more complex among these, as it has a very long range. At the same time it depends on how much of the value you are using.

Comment: Regarding range: `float` is the smallest type, as it has a finite number of values it can store. The number of possible `int` and `str` values is limited only by your machine's memory.